# Problem with system of implicit equations

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, systems-of-equations, implicit-function-theorem

I have some troubles with the next exercise. I'm preparing for an exam and I have been trying to solve this with no success.

> Justify that the system of equations
>   $$ uv - 3x + 2y = 0$$
>   $$u^4 - v^4 = x^2 - y^2$$
>   defines implicitly to $u$ and $v$ as functions of $(x,y)$ in $(1,1,1,1)$ and find the equations of tangent planes to the graphs of functions $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ in $(1,1)$.

I have solved this type of exercises with an only equation but I feel a bit lost with more ones. Any advice/help to solve this?

Comment: This is a system $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2 $ of the form $((x,y),(u,v)) \mapsto f((x,y),(u,v))$. Compute the derivative with respect to the first parameter ($(x,y)$) and show that it is invertible. Use the implicit function theorem.

Comment: Do you still need help with this? [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1683539/implicit-function-theorem-application-to-2-equations/1685455#1685455)'s a similar example.