# Explain the minus sign in the following formula.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

I just read that:

If $z=f(x,y)=c$, be the equation of a curve, then the slope of the tangent to the curve at any point (x,y), is given by
$$m=\frac {dy}{dx}=-\frac{\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}}{\frac {\partial z}{\partial y}}$$

I don't see how the minus sign creeps in here.(Of course I don't have a proof, but the - sign is against intuition).

A proof(or a link to a simple proof) would be nice, and an intuitive explanation would be nicer. Thanks for help.

Comment: [Example 1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/731725/question-about-implicit-function-theorem/731810#731810), [example 2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739814/multivariable-calculus-find-derivative-using-implicit-differentiation/742220#742220) and more generally see the statement of the implicit function theorem given [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/740152/multivariable-calculus-implicit-function-theorem/742703#742703). Note the part that says "Furthermore, $J_G=-\left(J_2\right)^{-1}J_1$".

Comment: This is an excellent counterexample to the statement that Leibniz notation is a fraction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As $z=f(x,y)=c$
$$\bigtriangledown z=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}dx+\frac {\partial z}{\partial y}dy=0$$
so$$
\frac {dy}{dx}=-\frac{\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}}{\frac {\partial z}{\partial y}}
$$

Comment: After doing a bit of reading on the internet, I (think I) finally understood your solution. What I learned besides was that I only knew 1% of the chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

This can be intuitively understood by realizing that we are calculating the Slope of the Tangents to the Level Curves of a Surface.

Level Curves (and thus their Tangents) always run Perpendicular to the Gradient Vector of the Surface.

The Gradient Vector has Slope ${f_y\over f_x}$.

The Slope of a Line Perpendicular to another has as Slope the Negative Reciprocal of the other Line's Slope.

Therefore the Implicit Derivative is $-{f_x\over f_y}$ because this is the Negative Reciprocal of the Slope of the Surface $f(x,y)$'s Gradient.

Answer (score 0):

From the chain rule, we get
$$ 
0 = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}} & \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \frac{dy}{dx}\end{pmatrix},
$$
which yields a linear equation
$$
\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}} \frac{dy}{dx} = - \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}.
$$

Now, we apply Cramer's rule to find $\frac{dy}{dx}.$ That is,
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{|- \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}|}{|\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}|} = \frac{-| \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}|}{|\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}|} = - \frac{ \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}}{\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}},
$$
where $|A|$ denotes the determinant of $A.$ Therefore, the minus sign is rather natural from the joint perspective of multivariable calculus and linear algebra.